# How to read ordered dictionary data in R

Tags: r, ordereddictionary

Assume that you have in a csv in column A the following Python "code"

```
"[OrderedDict([('YTC', 
OrderedDict([('V', 'B1')])), ('TA', '80'), ('TL', [OrderedDict([('TC', 
  OrderedDict([('V', 'B6'), ('SD', 'AA')])), ('Pe', '10')]), 
OrderedDict([('TC', 
  OrderedDict([('V', 'B5'), ('SD', 'BB')])), ('Pe', '90')]) ])])]"
```

etc

How can I read the respective variables/values in R?

Many thanks.

Comment: So that's an OrderedDict of OrderedDict ? Maybe look at the 'reticulate' package to read it first as a python OrderedDict and then import the values into R from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, test.csv contain your line in A1, just create a for loop if you have multiple lines:

```
library(reticulate)

test<-read.csv("D:/test.csv", header = FALSE)

test1<-strsplit(as.character(test$V1), split="", fixed=TRUE)
test1<-paste0(test1[[1]][2:(length(test1[[1]])-1)], collapse = "")

py_run_string("from collections import OrderedDict ")
py_run_string(paste0("od=", as.character(test1)))

items<-py_run_string("od.items()")

Rlist<-items$od #list of items in R
```

Comment: Many thanks! That really answers my question.